# JConsole Web Application

Tags: java, html, jmx, jconsole, mbeans

I need to have the information and operations of my MBeans in my applications and I need this to be as a web application.

My app server is Weblogic 10.3.2

Actually I need an application which can do the things(only about MBeans) like JConsole does(both functionally and visually).

ANy applications u know? or any code examples to do it easilly?

Thanks

Ali

Comment: In case of jboss/tomcat, the container already providing web console http://localhost:8080/web-console/ This could be leveraged to change MBeans at the run time similar to jconsole.

Comment: Sorry ,I missed the info that I am using weblogic as app server:) I have edited the question

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at:

1. [Jolokia](http://www.jolokia.org/): Deploys as a WAR or a JavaAgent and exposes JMX ops and attributes through a REST API. There's no actual console as yet, but check [here](https://github.com/rhuss/aji) and [here](http://nurkiewicz.blogspot.com/2011/03/jolokia-highcharts-jmx-for-human-beings.html) for possible implementations.
2. [OpenDMK](http://opendmk.java.net/): This is the open-sourced Java Dynamic Management Kit. It contains, among other things, a [HTML Protocol Adaptor](http://www.ireasoning.com/jmxdocs/com/sun/jdmk/comm/HtmlAdaptorServer.html) which provides a *very* basic browser accessible view of your MBeanServer.
3. [MX4J](http://mx4j.sourceforge.net/): Also provides an [HTTP Protocol Adaptor](http://mx4j.sourceforge.net/docs/ch05.html).

The last 2 are not particularly active any more, but I can attest to their stability.